# segmentation fault at global memory

Tags: c

First file:

```
//a.c

const int i = 9;   //Just contains the variable definition
```

Second file:

```
//b.c

#include<stdio.h>

extern int i;

int main()
{
    int *ptr = &i;

    printf("Before: %d\n",i);

    *ptr = 99;

    printf("After:  %d\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting `const` qualifier error/warning at `extern int i;` and read-only memory modification error in `*ptr = 99;` in **b.c**, but instead the compilation went fine.

1st print statement printed good but the second one gave *Segmentation fault*.

Why didn't it crash in the compilation stage with the anticipated errors and why it gave segmentation fault instead?

NOTE - **GCC 8.3.0**

Comment: that is why `extern`s should be put into headers

Comment: @tstanisl Please explain your comment

Comment: Because this code might run "totally fine" on some other system, for example on DOS.

Comment: I believe that it's not the `printf` line that crashes the program, but the `*ptr = 99;` line.

Comment: I am not getting the use case of your code. If you are defining a variable with const, then you are not expected to alter or modify the value. If you want to modify the global variable, then you should define your global variable without "const".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Translation units are compiled separately. Therefore the compiler has no idea that `i` is `const` in some other file. It trusts the declaration which is

```
extern int i;
```

There is no `const` there. That is why you see no warning.

To make sure that the similar error are detected early, it's advised to put declarations of global variables to a header file and let both `a.c` and `b.c` include this header.

In such a case the compiler would generate a diagnostic while compiling `a.c` because the declaration and the definition would be incompatible.

```
... a.h
#pragma once
extern int i;

... a.c
#include "a.h"
const int i = 9;

... b.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
    int *ptr = &i;

    printf("Before: %d\n",i);

    *ptr = 99;

    printf("After:  %d\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation command:

```
gcc a.c b.c
```

Error:

```
a.c:3:11: error: conflicting type qualifiers for ‘i’
    3 | const int i = 9;
      |           ^
In file included from a.c:1:
a.h:2:12: note: previous declaration of ‘i’ was here
    2 | extern int i;
      |            ^
```

---

*Edit*

While compiling `a.c` the compiler assumes that the object is constant and it is put into read-only memory. On Linux machines it will be put `.rodata` section that will be mapped to process' address space without `PROT_WRITE` flag.

When the memory is modified in `b.c` then segmentation fault exception (invalid access to memory) is raised and the program crashes.

Note that modifying a constant object triggers Undefined Behavior. The program could run for years and then suddenly start crashing.

Comment: This does not explain why the program crashes (and indeed is not the reason why it crashes)

Comment: @DanielKleinstein, I guess the question was why the invalid code compiles successfully. My answer should help OP avoid similar issues in future.

Answer (score 6):

Attempting to write to a `const int` through a pointer is undefined behavior per the standard.

What's probably happening in practice is that your variable is placed in the executable's `.rodata` region - which is marked read-only in memory - and when you attempt to write to it through the pointer it triggers a page fault that crashes the program.

---

Removing the `const` should fix this, if you need to write to the variable.

Comment: Then that should've not compiled at all due attempt to modify read-only memory.

Comment: No - the compiler has no way of knowing that your `extern int i` is a const placed in `.rodata`.

Comment: This is a runtime error, not a compile time one.

Answer (score 1):

*"I was expecting const qualifier error/warning at extern int i; and read-only memory modification error in *ptr = 99; in b.c, but instead the compilation went fine."*

`a.b` and `b.c`,  although each as stand-alone are syntactically correct, each  occupies its own compilation unit, with nothing tying their contents together.  Their is nothing to cause a compile conflict because the contents of one have zero visibility of the contents of the other.

As written,

```
const int i = 9;//in a.c
```

and

```
extern int i;//in b.c
```

occupy two completely autonomous places in memory,and although they share the same symbol, have no relationship whatsoever, except that at run-time they are participants within the same process. (if one is not optimized out.)

It is unclear whether your question derives from the need to deploy actual code, or just as a learning project. Either way, when it is desired to have a project global variable, a proper way to do it (some would say [idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files) way)  is to:

- *declare* an `extern` in a header file
- #include that header file in in any `.c` file that will Use it
- Finally, *define* it in [global space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) *once* in one of the `.c` files that will use it.

Eg:

a.h

```
extern int i; //declare here
```

a.c

```
#include "a.h"
...
int i = 0;//define in global space and use here 
          //(often in file containing main() function)
```

b.c

```
   #include "a.h"
   ...
   int *ptr = &i; //use here
```

Now you have a single instance of globally visible variable that can be accessed from both `a.c` and `b.c`,  As such, the potential for conflict now exists and because both `.c` files can see and act on the single instance of `i`, the way it is declared and defined will be scrutinized differently during compilation, across all compilation units.  Inconsistencies will be seen and flagged.